# Is it possible to let my rPi connect to a Wifi with a given SSID without a monitor, keyboard, mouse and LAN?

Tags: wifi, internet

Is it possible to let my rPi connect to a Wifi with a given SSID without a monitor, keyboard, mouse and LAN? Let's say I brought my Pi with me and want to access a public Wifi and I only have a Mac with no ethernet port.

Comment: It depends. If you have a `Linux` computer and use `Raspbian` (not `NOOBS`) it is possible, but it is easier if you can borrow hardware for setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll post my own solution. I used a Mac and an Android phone (probably optional).

1. Setup your Android Phone for tethering.
2. Before bringing your rPi to the wild, at home plug it in a monitor and update `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to include the information for your Android private network SSID.

`$ sudo vim /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

I appended my Android Private Network to the end

```
  ...

  network={
     ssid="AtHome"
     psk="aSecurePassphrase"
     key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
  }

  network={
     ssid="myAndroidNetwork"
     psk="aMoreSecurePassphrase"
     key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
  }
```

3. Outside your home, turn on tethering in Android and turn on rPi.
4. In your Mac execute `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`
5. Then perform step 2 again appending the new public wifi SSID

It should look something like this

```
  ...

  network={
     ssid="AtHome"
     psk="aSecurePassphrase"
     key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
  }

  network={
     ssid="myAndroidNetwork"
     psk="aMoreSecurePassphrase"
     key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
  }

  network={
     ssid="newPublicWifiSSID"
     psk="theMostSecurePassphrase"
     key_mgmt=WPA_PSK
  }
```

6. Turn off tethering in Android phone and reboot rPi.

*NOTE* I am guessing that the Android phone is not necessary if you can make your Mac an access point.

Comment: There are also Android SSH clients that could give you terminal access to the pi once it is tethered.  I don't know know if that will make it easier or harder in this context.  Using a console on a phone is pretty tedious and the app probably needs to provide things like a `ctrl` key to make it useful for quick editing of text files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.

You can mount sd card on your Mac. Edit file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` on root partition according to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) tutorial.

If Mac cannot read `ext4` partitions use 3rd party software to mount and edit files. Also if there isn't any software, try to use Linux LiveCD(for ex. Ubuntu).

Comment: The Mac cannot access `ext4` partitions.